# Haskell recursion in IO action

Tags: haskell, recursion, io, do-notation

Still a beginner that can't figure out a recursive loop in an `IO` action. Assume:

```
fMinInspect :: Int
fMinInspect = 1
fMaxInspect :: Int
fMaxInspect = 12
-- fNoInspectPerHour :: IO ()
fNoInspectPerHour = do
  generateInspect <- randomRIO (fMinInspect,fMaxInspect)
  putStrLn ""
```

I would like to generate a list for let's say 10 machines I want randomly checked, can I then make a repeated call to something that would add 10x `fNoInspectPerHour` to a list?

I tried an external function, but I can't get the actions from the `IO ()`. Note that `putStrLn` is just to terminate the `do`-block, since I don't need console output.

PS. suggestions on terminating a `do`-block without the `putStrLn` is welcome too.

Comment: Just use `return ()`; that's the simplest way to create an `IO ()` value.

Comment: Otherwise, it's not clear what you want. Do you want a list of 10 random numbers?

Comment: As is, `fNoInspectPerHour` doesn't really do anything except modify the state of the random number generator; it doesn't do anything with the random number it generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually meant to use recursion yourself here, you could write e.g.

```
fNoInspectPerHour :: Int -> IO () 
fNoInspectPerHour 0 = return () 
fNoInspectPerHour n = do { 
    generateInspect <- randomRIO (fMinInspect,fMaxInspect) ; 
    --  Int            IO Int
    putStrLn generateInspect ;    -- or do some other IO action
    --                 IO ()
    fNoInspectPerHour (n-1) 
    --                 IO ()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`randomIO (fMinInspect, fMaxInspect)` is an IO action, a value of type `(Num a, Random a) => IO a`. (For simplicity, we'll assume that `a` is `Int` from now on.)
Note that each execution of the action can generate a *different* random value; that's the difference between `IO Int` being an *action* that generates a random value and being a random value itself.

Once we have that action, we can create a list of actions with `replicate 10 (randomRIO (fMinInspect, fMaxInspect))`; this will have type `[IO Int]`, 10 copies of an IO action.

The `sequence` function can change your list of IO actions into an IO action that yields a list of values (each value being produced by the corresponding action), converting a value of type `[IO Int]` into a value of type `IO [Int]`.

```
> fMinInspect = 1
> fMaxInspect = 12
> sequence (replicate 10 (randomRIO (fMinInspect, fMaxInspect)))
[1,6,6,1,7,5,8,4,7,7]
```

(Here, as usual, GCHi is executing the IO action, which was produced by `sequence`, and returns the result produced by that IO action.)

Comment: ...and this combination of `sequence` and `replicate` is so common that it's got a standard name, `replicateM`.

Comment: Oh, I thought that existed, but it didn't seem to be in scope. I had to import `Control.Monad` first.

Comment: Thanks @Chepner and Daniel Wagner. That certainly helped me out.. Still got a lot to learn. Haskell's trying to keep it interesting.

Comment: By the way @Chepner: your example works from the prompt, but how to incorporate in the do-block....?

Comment: Why do you need a `do` block? It's still not clear what the purpose of `fNoInspectPerHour` is, since it doesn't do anything with the generated number.

Comment: I mean, you can write `replicateM 3 fNoInspectPerHour` to get a value of `IO [(), (),  ()]`, but unless you actually yield each random number, what's the point?

Comment: @Madderote you can write `fNoInspectPerHour = do { 
  generateInspectList <- sequence (replicate 10 (randomRIO (fMinInspect,fMaxInspect))) ;
  print generateInspectList }` if that's what you meant to do.

Comment: @Chepner, first need to get them before I can use them, but your insights and those of Will Ness already helped solving it. I am apparently struggling also with the number of ways to address problems in Haskell. Thanks!!

Comment: @Madderote great to hear that it helps. Keep at it, keep asking on SO (and elsewhere), and keep keeping engaged on your questions! :)